# Assign <th> tag to first column in PHP generated table

Tags: php, html, charts, html-table

Using this function from a different to generate a table from a PHP query.  I'm trying to generate charts from using the filament jQuery visualize plugin.  Nearly there however it seems that I need to tag each value in the first column as `<th>` in order for the charts to properly recognise it as a header.  I think I need to put an if statement in in terms of 'if the column number is 1, append `<th>` to it' but unsure where this would go in the below code.  Any ideas?

```
function SQLResultTable($Query)
{
    $host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "Quality_Monitoring";
    $link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());      //build MySQL Link
    mysql_select_db($db) or die('Could not select database');        //select database
    $Table = "";  //initialize table variable

    $Table.= "<table id='Table1' border='1' style=\"border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center; font-size: 10px; cellspacing: 5px; \">"; //Open HTML Table

    $Result = mysql_query($Query); //Execute the query
    if(mysql_error())
    {
        $Table.= "<tr><td>MySQL ERROR: " . mysql_error() . "</td></tr>";
    }
    else
    {
        //Header Row with Field Names
        $NumFields = mysql_num_fields($Result);
            $Table.="<thead>";
        $Table.= "<tr style=\"background-color: #000066; text-align: center; color: #FFFFFF;\">";

        for ($i=0; $i < $NumFields; $i++)
        {   
        if($i==0){  
            $Table.= "<th>" . "</th>";}
            else {
            $Table.= "<th>" . mysql_field_name($Result, $i) . "</th>";
            }

        }

        $Table.= "</tr>";
    $Table.="</thead>";
        //Loop thru results
        $RowCt = 0; //Row Counter
        while($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result))
        {
            //Alternate colors for rows
            if($RowCt++ % 2 == 0) $Style = "background-color: #CCCCCC;";
            else $Style = "background-color: #FFFFFF;";

            $Table.= "<tr style=\"$Style\">";
            //Loop thru each field
            foreach($Row as $field => $value)
            {
                $Table.= "<td>$value</td>";
            }
            $Table.= "</tr>";
        }
       // $Table.= "<tr style=\"background-color: #000066; color: #FFFFFF;\"><td colspan='$NumFields'>Query Returned " . mysql_num_rows($Result) . " records</td></tr>";
    }
    $Table.= "</table>";

    return $Table;

}

?>
```

I know I should be using MYSQLI or whatever, I will resolve that soon, just need to get this prototype up and running.  Any help greatly appreciated.

The table it generates is this:

```
<table id="Table1" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center; font-size: 10px; cellspacing: 5px; ">
<thead>
<tr style="background-color: #000066; text-align: center; color: #FFFFFF;">
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr style="background-color: #CCCCCC;">
<td>Alex O Halloran</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>2.5</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
<td>Christopher Fox</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>3.0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color: #CCCCCC;">
<td>Dan McCrory</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>1.5</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
<td>Jacob Desborough</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>1.0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color: #CCCCCC;">
<td>Katy Hill</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>1.4</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

In this example, I would need the names to be tagged as `</th>` - hope this helps clarify what I'm after.

Comment: This is really bad code. Do you mean to be inserting an empty <th /> tag as the first field? I think the question needs an example raw HTML output so we can visualise what it is you know you need to achieve based on your use of jQuery.

Comment: @deed02392 Not an Empty one, but all the first field/column values would need to be tagged as a </th>

Comment: The code is saying for the first field of the header row, don't put in the field name. You need to make this question more readable or no one's going to help you. Help us help you and put a bit of your own effort into understanding what you've got and explaining what you need...

Comment: @deed02392 added in the table markup, I got rid of the first column header as I don't need a value in there, just need to convert all the fileds in the table where there's a name into a </th> rather than a </td>  sorry if I'm unclear, I'm totally new to all of this so find it hard to explain exactly what I need in anything other than laymans terms.

Comment: I basically need it to work like these charts here, where it understands the names as series http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/jqueryui-visualize/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using :

```
$first = true;
foreach($Row as $field => $value) {
    if ($first) {
        $Table .= "<th>$value</th>";
        $first = false;
    } else {
        $Table.= "<td>$value</td>";
    }
}
```

Let me know if I misunderstood your question

Comment: This looks like the solution you want, but I'm not sure why you aren't getting any field names inserted along the top in your example HTML output. Don't forget you probably want `<th scope="row">`, according to the example you linked.

Comment: Excellent, thankyou, that fixed that issue, now just for some reason on the chart the labels are all offset by 2 series to the right, so the first lable is assigned to the 3rd series, with blanks for the first 2 series.  BUT, your solution solved the question I was asking, I guess this labels business is just a CSS issue somewhere, Thanks so much, really appreciate it!